# Java 8 interfaces

Tags: java

I have:

```
public class CustomSheet extends XSSFSheet implements customSheetsI
```

In XSSFSheet there is a method,

```
public XSSFWorkbook getWorkbook() {
    return (XSSFWorkbook)this.getParent();
}
```

In my customSheet class I want to Override the getWorkbook method (or add a new getCustomWorkbook) casting the Workbook to a customWorkbook. I can do it in every instance of my interface, but I would like to take advantage of Java 8 and write the method directly in the interface.

Something like this

```
    public interface customSheetsI<T extends XSSFSheet>
    {
        default LogChunkWorkbook getLogWorkbook() {
            return (LogChunkWorkbook)getWorkbook();
        }
..
```

using the getWorkbook from the super class XSSFSheet. But it doesn't work like I wrote. It doesn't know about getWorkbook. How can I do this?

Comment: The default method can only refer to methods declared in the current interface or one of its superinterfaces. For pretty obvious reasons.

Comment: thanks. So basically there is no way for doing this without implementing also the getParent (for instance). Correct?

Comment: That's it, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also add the `getWorkbook()` method in your interface, and implement it in `CustomSheet`. You will be able to you use it like this:

```
public interface customSheetsI {
    default String getLogWorkbook() {
        return (String) getWorkbook();
    }

    YourReturnType getWorkbook();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `CustomSheet` is, at the same time, a XSSFSheet (why it has `getWorkbook()`) and implements `customSheetsI` which you want to make use of that.

Now, you have several alternatives to go:

- Create an `abstract class AbstractCustomSheet extends XSSFSheet implements customSheetsI` which can define its `getLogWorkbook()` the way you describe
- Derive your `customSheetsI` from [`Sheet`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html) so that it already has the needed `getWorkbook()`
- Create an "in-between" interface which derives from `customSheetsI` and from [`Sheet`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html) so that it already has the needed `getWorkbook()`

All them tell the class or interface which implement your `getLogWorkbook()` that a suitable `getWorkbook()` is at hand.

Comment: yep thanks. I also thought at an extra abstract class, but I don't want another extra class only for this getWorkbook. I guess I will go for the second option

Answer (score 0):

Invoke `getWorkbook()` in `customSheetsI` is crasy. Image that if you have a class which implements `customSheetsI` but not extents `XSSFSheet`, how could Java to resolve `getWorkbook()` when you called `getLogWorkbook()`. I suggest you may come from dynamic language(like Ruby, Python) world and expect the `VM` to throw an exception when it can't resolve the method. In fact, in Java, it's more static.

To resolve you problem, I think you need one more class to extends `XSSFSheet`, let name it `MyXSSFSheet` and add `getLogWorkbook` in it, then make all your class which formerly extend `XSSFSheet` to extend `MyXSSFSheet`.

PS: The name of `customSheetsI` is not so common to naming a interface in Java, it would better to use the Camel naming with capital first letter.